# How to avoid assigning to the heap

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to improve performance by not using malloc in a loop. As the size of the array is almost always the same size I'm trying to use a stack variable and only replacing it if the array is too big. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the behaviour I'm getting.
Here is my code snippit. Is there anything obviously wrong here.

```
    double *A
    if(n>1024){
        A = malloc( n * sizeof( *A ) );
        if( !A ) {
               fprintf( stderr, "Failed to allocate phi in calculate_forces()\n" );
               exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    else{
        double a[1024];
        A=a;
    }
```

Comment: What behavior are you expecting and what are you actually getting?

Comment: Can you malloc outside the loop and use realloc inside - or realloc only when size increases

Comment: the `double a[1024]` will go out of scope in the else block

Comment: Why do you compare against `if(!phi)` in the if when you allocate `A`

Comment: @hmjd: Why did you delete your answer?  It was the best one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Visual C++, you can use the `_malloca/_freea` pair of functions to automatically switch between stack and heap allocation, based on a threshold (which happens to be yours - 1K).  If you're on another compiler, you can create your own equivalents of these.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing one brace, thus changing the logic implemented

```
double *A
if(n>1024){
    A = malloc( ng * sizeof( *phi ) );
    if( !phi ) {
           fprintf( stderr, "Failed to allocate phi in calculate_forces()\n" );
           exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}                 // this is the brace you need to add <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
else{
    double a[1024];
    A=a;
}
```

EDIT:

There are other problems with your code, like assigning `a` to `A`, where `a` lives shorter than `A`, not being able to tell if you need to call `free`, using `n` and `ng` instead of only one of those - probably a bug, and probably also mixing up `phi` and `A`